# Get the accuracy of a random forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I have created a `random forest` out of my data:

```
fit=randomForest(churn~., data=data_churn[3:17], ntree=1,
                 importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
```

I can easily see my `confusion matrix`:

```
conf <- fit$confusion
> conf
     No Yes class.error
No  945  80  0.07804878
Yes  84 101  0.45405405
```

Now I need to know the accuracy for the random forest. I searched around and realized that [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf) library has a `confusionMatrix` method that gets a confusion matrix and returns the accuracy (alongside with many other values). However, the method needs another parameter called `"reference"`. My question is how can I provide a reference for the method to get the accuracy of my random forest?
And... is it the correct way to get the accuracy of a random forest?

Comment: If you just type `fit` at the command prompt, both the confusion matrix and out of bag (OOB) error will print out. The OOB error is the overall classification error. You can also calculate the OOB error from the confusion matrix. In your case, it's 164/1210 (the number of misclassified observations over the total number of observations). However, if you really want to know how good your model is, you should have separate training data to create the model and test data (that wasn't used in the model-building process) to check the model's performance.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks! So I am assuming that the accuracy would be 1-OOB error. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: FYI You're aware that choosing `ntree=1` gives just one rpart tree, not a forest?

Comment: @smci Yes. Thanks for your comment though. I would change the number of trees in execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `randomForest(..., do.trace=T)` to see the OOB error during training, by both class and ntree.

(FYI you chose `ntree=1` so you'll only get just one rpart decision-tree, not a forest, this kind of defeats the purpose of using RF, and of randomly choosing a subset of both features and samples. You probably want to vary `ntree` values.)

And after training, you can get per-class error from the rightmost column of the confusion matrix as you already found:

```
> fit$confusion[, 'class.error']
class.error
No         Yes
0.07804878 0.45405405
```

(Also you probably want to set `options('digits'=3)` to not see those excessive decimal places)

As to converting that list of class errors (*accuracies = 1 - errors*) to one overall accuracy number, that's easy to do. You could use **mean, class-weighted mean, harmonic mean** (of accuracies, not of errors) etc. It depends on your application and the relative penalty for misclassifying. Your example is simple, it's only two-class.

(or e.g. there are more complicated measures of inter-rater agreement)